# Finding the Datetime of a row in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've written a code in DAX (in the excel power query) to find the MAX and MIN of a column in a summarized table, and now **I want to find the DateTimeStamp in its row in the summarized table**.
My summarized Table is shown in the image below.

[My Table that I have previously found the MAX and MIN Value and Now I want to find its DateTimeStamp in its row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOGSM.jpg)

As it is evident in the Table the MAX and MIN of the Value column are found and now I want to have their respective DateTimeStamp from the DateTimeStamp column which is :

Respective DateTimeStamp of the MAX Value is : 2022-07-28 10:00:00

Respective DateTimeStamp of the MIN Value is : 2022-07-28 10:02:00

I wrote a code to find the DateTimeStamp but it does not appear on my pivot table and it gets stuck on the loading condition. My code is presented below:

```
CALCULATE(Max(Table[DateTimeStamp]),
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(Table, Table[DateTimeStamp],
            "SumValue",IF(COUNTROWS(Table)=calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[Name]),ALLSELECTED()),SUM(Table[Value]),BLANK())),
            [SumValue]=[HighValue])         
    )
```

where the `HighValue` is the MAX Value I've found previously.

Thanking you in advance for your kind guidance.

Comment: Perhaps some raw copiable data with expected result would be helpful.

Comment: in your sample, some of the sums are blank, is there a reason for that ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @UmutK yes there is a reason for that. I want to only calculate the sum when all 3 Names (x,y,z) exist for the specific DateTimeStamp. So when there are 2 or 1 Name exists for the specific DateTimeStamp so the sum should not be calculated and it should be BLANK.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm looking for the Datetime value of the MAX and MIN in the DateTimeStamp column. I mean in the current Table I'm looking for a DAX code to return 2022-07-28 10:00:00 as the MAX datetime and return 2022-07-28 10:02:00 as the MIN datetime.